# Is it possible to compile a Jekyll site running on github?

Tags: html, github, compilation, static, jekyll

I have a Jekyll site running on github pages. I want to transfer all the content on a private hosting that doesn't allow a Jekyll installation.

Is there a way to "compile" the markdown and the configurations and get a standalone version of the website so it can be hosted as simple HTML + PHP + CSS?

Comment: yes you can do it. Just follow the tutorial. https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-up-your-github-pages-site-locally-with-jekyll

Comment: The link you provided is for when you have a local project already. I don't. I have only a github hosted theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the GitHub Page site is 100%, all you need to do is download all of its pages.

```sh
$ wget \
     --recursive \
     --no-clobber \
     --page-requisites \
     --html-extension \
     --convert-links \
     --domains example.com \
     --no-parent \
     www.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1: CloudCannon

Use Github for versioning and use their platform to build your site (make sure you load the right gems for your theme). In Settings set your Output Syncing to 'FTP'. I think a paid account is required.

### Option 2: Forestry.io

Use Github for versioning and use their platform to build your site (make sure you load the right gems for your theme). In Settings set your Deploy to 'FTP'. I think a free account is enough to do so.

### Option 3: Localhost

I know you did not want this... but it is the simplest solution. Use Github for versioning and build locally (make sure you load the right gems for your theme). Then upload the content of the _site folder through FTP to your server. Absolutely free.